# Errno 13 Permission denied: with zipf

Tags: python, windows, file-permissions

I have a python program to write a zip file in folder B (a remote location) with an entire folder tree from folder A (c:\workspace). But dont know why I cannot write that folder A.

From permissions side, I am using the local administrator account, and I can read and write from that folder. I have already tried to force to run with admin privileges through cmd but same result. From folder permissions, as an admin I have special privileges in that folder.

This is the part where I zip the entire folder content including subfolders:

```
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(dst, 'w',zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
                                for root, folders, files in os.walk(SRC):
                                        print ('root> %s' %root)
                                        #logging.debug('root> %s' %root)
                                        print ('folders> %s' %folders)
                                        #logging.debug('folders> %s' %folders)
                                        print ('files> %s'%files)
                                        #logging.debug('files> %s'%files)
                                        for foldername in folders:
                                                print ('foldername> %s' %foldername)
                                                foldername_path = os.path.join (root,foldername)
                                                print ('foldername_path> %s' %foldername_path)
                                                zipf.write(foldername_path)
                                        for filename in files:
                                                print ('filename> %s' %filename)
                                                filename_path = os.path.join (root,filename)
                                                print ('filename_path> %s' %filename_path)
                                                zipf.write(filename_path)
                                zipf.close()
```

This is the output:

> root> c:\workspace\ folders> ['django-rev7543', 'www_server']
>
> files>['backup.log']
>
> foldername> django-rev7543
>
> foldername_path>> c:\workspace\django-rev7543
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Scripts\master_backup.py", line 178, in  backup_files()
>
> File "C:\Scripts\master_backup.py", line 102, in backup_files email_error_notification(e)
>
> File "C:\Scripts\master_backup.py", line 176, in email_error_notification
>
> sys.exit(1) SystemExit: 1

In my logfile where errors are being saved:

> 2017-05-04 10:46:38,046 root         DEBUG    [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\workspace\django-rev7543'
>
> 2017-05-04 10:46:38,078 root  DEBUG    not all arguments converted during string formatting

For test purposes I have target that subfolder (django-rev7543) to be zpif and I can also write there. In this program I am writing a log file.

After all, seems like I can read and write, but when trying to zipf any folder or file, I get permission denied. =/

This script was running without problem in another machine, but was not messing around with C:/ folders or subfolders.

Versions:

- Python 2.5.4
- Windows XP SP3

UPDATE 1:

With a previous program that I was using, using shutil.copy2 I was able to copy without problem, but it was just one file..

Comment: try opening the cmd with run as administrator and then run the program or go to the properties of the folder and security and then change the permission for the logged in user

Comment: @Exprator same result in both cases =/

Comment: can you move your program to another drive and try to save in that drive and not in C:\ drive. means code in D:\ and save zip also in D:\

Comment: @Exprator The problem here is the source folder being at C: root. I tried to exec this program in my documents, using as target folder another folder inside of my documents, and made it as expected to the remote location. Then with the previous target folder at C: and same result. With a previous program that I was using, using shutil.copy2 I was able to copy without problem, but it was just one file. This just seems to happean when I try to add the content to a zip folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that zipf under python 2.5 doesnt zip empty folders, but OSError return this as **Errno 13 Permission denied**.

To use zipf without any restrictions it should be used at least in python 3.4 (Didnt check if it works for all versions of python 3 before 3.4).